# scalikejdbc and MySQL subquery WHERE IN (SELECT statement)

Tags: scalikejdbc

It looks like scalikejdbc doesn't support MySQL's `WHERE IN (SELECT statement)` [queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html), as `IN` requires a sequence of items as a parameter, it doesn't accept a query.

Any ideas for making it work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `sqls.in()` supports `SQLSyntax` as a second parameter.